# Drupal Module : how to add fields to another module content type?

Tags: drupal, module, field, content-type

I am writing my first drupal module...

The goal is to add "permissions" to the drupal_wall module, in order to authorize the view of a post or not depending on several conditions / configurations.

I then thought adding a field "permissions" to the drupal_wall content type.

I would like to do it programmatically on my module install.

I managed to define my module and its dependencies and found how to implement hook_install().

I think the solution will use field_create_field() and field_create_instance(), but I don't know how to refer/access the drupal_wall content type.

Thank you for your help,

Answer (score 0):

If you have the content-type of posts, you can implement [hook_node_access](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_access/7.x) in a custom module.
In that way you don't need to add a field and modify the implementation of a different module: with your solution a future update of drupal_wall could break your module and your website.